# How do I write a macOS app without an IDE?

Tags: macos, cocoa

How do I write a macOS app that just gets a window up, without an IDE?

PS. Rant:

Programming is very simple, it's writing code invoking some libraries, typing a clang command and watching the CPU execute the program.

Why is every page of Apple programmer documentation a thousand words about nothing and zero words about which library classes to use in the `main` method of your simple program to get a macOS window up.

How do I get a macOS window up in my `main` function? It could have been like 5 lines in a `hello.c` file compiled with one `clang` command. Not opening massive Xcode and fiddling forever with random IDE features that I'm not interested in.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While I understand your frustration, this site [doesn't like rants in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In order to receive positive feedback and - more importantly - good answers, I'd recommend re-phrasing your question.

Comment: Good feedback, it makes sense. Sorry about the rant.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, this is a swift file that when compiled and run will get a macOS window up:

```
import Cocoa
let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), styleMask: .titled, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
NSApp.run()
```

Comment: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html